# Unexpected javascript response

Tags: javascript

Here is my code first of all,

```
$(function() {
    var fee_percent = parseFloat('<?php echo $gateway["gateway_fees"]; ?>');
    var fee_fixed = parseFloat('<?php echo $gateway["gateway_fixed_fees"]; ?>');
    var min = parseFloat('<?php echo $gateway["min_invest_limit"]; ?>');
    var max = parseFloat('<?php echo $gateway["max_invest_limit"]; ?>');


    $("#amountId").on('change keyup keydown', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var val = parseFloat($this.val());
        val = val.toFixed(5);

        var valid = true;

        var fee = parseFloat(val * fee_percent / 100) + fee_fixed;
        fee = fee.toFixed(5);

        var final_amount = val - fee;
        final_amount = final_amount.toFixed(5);

        console.log("value: " + val);
        console.log("fee: " + fee);
        console.log("final: " + final_amount);
        console.log("min: " + min.toFixed(5));
        console.log("max: " + max.toFixed(5));

        if(val <= 0 || isNaN(val) || fee > val || val < min.toFixed(5) || val > max.toFixed(5)) fee = final_amount = 0;

        $("#depositFee").html(fee);
        $("#depositAmountFinal").html(final_amount);
    });
});
```

and now my problem is, 
`val > max.toFixed(5)` this is always returning TRUE.

Here is the console response :

value: 11.00000
fee: 0.46000
final: 10.54000
min: 10.00000
max: 10000.00000

so the value is 11 and max value in 10000, then why its false ?

If its not clear, please ask, thanks.

UPDATE : when I type 10, 100, or 1000 and so on, it works fine.

If I don't use `max.toFixed(5)` but instead I use only `max`, everything works fine but when I type some value with 5 in the end, like 55, 65, 75 and so on, the condition become true again, that should return false.

Comment: 11 is less than 10000, so it should be returning false.  Sure you don't want to be using the < operator?

Comment: 11 is always less than 10000. Then it should return false only.

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, actually the condition returns true on that, but actually that is not correct so I said false.

Comment: @mohamedrias: `"11" > "10000"` :-)

Comment: @mohamedrias OK I take your example, now tell me, this condition will work or no ? `fee = final_amount = 0;`, this is from that if condition block, so if value is 11 and max is 10000, `fee = final_amount = 0;` should run or no ? According to me, NO, but actually it runs, that's my problem.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi toFixed returns us String. So 1 followed by 1 is greater than 1 followed by 0. That's why "11" is greater than "10000" :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toFixed` returns you String.

So `"11" > "10000"` returns you `true` because. 1 followed by 1 is greater than 1 followed by 0

You can try in your console:

`"01" > "0001"` will return you `true` which is also based on the same concept.

To avoid it :

```
parseFloat(val) > parseFloat(max.toFixed(5))
```

Comment: This seems true, but whats the solution ?

Comment: Updated answer. parseFloat and check

Comment: It's because the interpreter is trying to type cast both operands to same type. when it was just 5 it converted "11.000" to number. But when it became 55 it converted it to String. And note that val in your case is having .toFixed. so it;s a string

Comment: I tried parseFloat thing already, but see the last part of my question, I updated, that happens when I use parseFloat, when I type 545, or 555 it works, but when I type 565 or 575, again returns true.

Comment: No when you use parseFloat for both operands its working fine. I have tested different combinations.

Comment: I used parseFloat in every variable in that if condition, now its working all good, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correct:

```
val = 11;

max = 10000;

if(val > max)

if(11 **is greater than** 10000)
```

It should return false. 11 is not higher than 10,000.

Comment: It should be a comment

Comment: @mohamedrias Genuinely curious, why is that? Many times have I asked a question where the issue is a simple syntax error or misunderstanding of my own code, where people have posted answers which I have accepted.

Comment: I understand. I thought that the OP's original question may be different. Because that's obvious that 11 > 10000 is always false. So only mentioned. But great to see you explaining it there. Keep up

Comment: @Matt This is not at all a syntax error, I am testing my code with every possibility, I want that you read my question again, and then see if you can help me solve this.

Comment: @Matt What you saying in your answer is correct, it should return false, but it is returning true.